# refresh rate for gyroscop and accelerometer [ mpu6050 ]

Tags: accelerometer, gyro, imu

What is refresh rate ( update rate) for gyroscop and accelerometer ? If you write in the register the following values in mpu6050 :

SMPLRT_DIV --> 19

CONFIG --> 2 ( DLPF off )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the first thing is to look at the register map of MPU6050 ( that is mostly named as register map MPU6000)

According to the formula given in the CONFIG register description

Sample Rate = Gyroscope output rate / (1+SMPLRT_DIV)

Over here you have chosen Gyroscope rate as 1KHz , hence your sample rate comes to 50 Hz   i.e 50 Samples per second.